# Astro build version routes not working at all

Tags: javascript, routes, url-routing, astrojs

I've been building a project with astro, everything worked perfectly fine in the dev mode and the preview mode but whenever I build the app all routes just point to the index.astro file and if I delete it, there is basically no routes at all.

In order to identify the problem, I tried replicating the problem on a smaller scale and it just doesn't seem to not work even on the simplest form of app.

I'm really confused, this problem seems so basics that I feel certain I'm probably the one missing something.

If anybody have any solution, it would be of a great help, thank you !

### Here is the file structures which should be defining the route :

```
ty
├── src/
│   └── pages/
│       └── index.astro
        |__ agenda.astro
        |-- serie.astro
        |deuxieme_etage/maison.astrope here
```

---

They all work as espected when I run npm start, npm run preview but whenever I get the build version with npm run build, it doesn't.

I served it using serve -s dist doesn't work, also tried it on my production website also and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `serve -s dist commands` only return a single page website so the right command would be to use `serve dist`.

Also in my astro.config file I declared the build format to 'file', that fixed the problem on my production server.